# React-Native integration Support for V2 Pro device SunMI

Tags: android, ios, react-native, xiaomi

I want to develop app for both iOS and Android Platform via react-native. Is there any available SDK of SUNMI V2 Pro(https://www.sunmi.com/en/V2Pro/) in react-native???

Here is the library i got: https://github.com/januslo/react-native-sunmi-inner-printer

I am not sure what exactly it does. Let me know the correct way of integration.

Answer (score 1):

I use this library, just follow the documentation like any other library, and if you are confused about the format you can see it in the folder example/index.android.js, but I have never tried it for iOS, because Sunmi just use Android devices